# react-datepicker fails with moment and new Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs

I am trying to set `minDate` property in [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) component with `moment`:

```
if(this.props.minDate){
      console.log('date:' + moment(this.props.minDate)); //1517436000000

      return <DatePicker

       minDate={ new moment(this.props.minDate)} 
         selected={this.state.startDate}
         onChange={this.handleChange}
         disabled = {this.props.disabled}
     />
```

or with `new Date`:

```
console.log('new date:' + new Date(this.props.minDate)); // Thu Feb 01 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0200
return <DatePicker

       minDate={ new Date(this.props.minDate)} 
         selected={this.state.startDate}
         onChange={this.handleChange}
         disabled = {this.props.disabled}
     />
```

My minDate String - `"2011-10-01"`.
And still the result is the current day and the are no errors in the console, thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this custom made DatePicker or are you using AirBnB component or something else... ?

Comment: using package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Answer (score 1):

I think You have to give value for this, because minDate and maxDate are for validation purpose.
minDate will only be the resulting value only if, when given value or current date is less then min Date

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.minDate = new moment(props.minDate)
    this.state = {
      startDate: props.minDate
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <DatePicker
     selected={this.state.startDate}
     onChange={this.handleChange}
     minDate={this.minDate}
     value={this.props.startDate}
   />;
  }
}
```

Comment: my problem was with `selected` property that overwrite `minDate` property.

Comment: I have added an example, please check will it work or not. That is what i meant we have to pass the value to over ride selected value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you do not need new instance of moment when you pass data to minDate prop. You are doing it like this `minDate={ new moment(this.props.minDate)}`.

React-datepicker already internally uses moment for manipulating data objects so I think you should just remove keyword new in front of a moment when you are passing it to the minDate prop.

Comment: my problem was with `selected` property that overwrite `minDate` property.

Answer (score 0):

I figure this one myself, it appears that if `selected` property is set, it will shown and not the  `minDate` property.